Obtaining covariates ' standard errors in rdrobust package in R
I am using rdrobust in R to estimate RDD's with covariates. I would like to know how I can estimate or obtain the (robust) standard errors for these covariates please.
I have tried the RDestimates package too but I cannot obtain either the coefficient or the standard errors of the covariates.
It would be great if you know let me know how to do it in both of them or just one of them please.
Thank you.
